# Can velocity in $y$-axis be equal with velocity in $x$-axis?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors

So if $u_y=30 m/s$ and $u_x=30 m/s$ can we say that $u_y=u_x$? my confusion is because velocity is vector they are not equal ( equal in magnitude but not dimension). But  can we say that they are equal in magnitude?

Answer (score 2):

$u_x$ and $u_y$ are components of a vector and are numbers. In order to write the vector these numbers must be multiplied with unit vectors $\hat x$ and $\hat y$. Thus one can say that $u_x = u_y$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can say that $u_y=u_x$.

$u_y$ and $u_x$ are scalars. You multiply them by the unit vectors, $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{i}$, to get the actual vectors, $u_{y}\vec{j}$ and $u_{x}\vec{i}$.

When writers refer to 'components' of velocity (or any other vector), you usually have to work out from context whether they mean the scalar coefficients ($u_y$ and $u_x$ in your case) or the vector components, $u_{y}\vec{j}$ and $u_{y}\vec{i}$. Your context told me that your question was about *scalar* coefficients.

Comment: The components of a vector aren't scalars. Scalars don't change under coordinate transformations.

Comment: @user7777777 The way you represent components can change under transformation, but if you are working in a certain coordinate system the components can be thought of as scalars.

Comment: I was using the terms 'scalar component' and 'vector component' as defined by Synge and Griffiths (Principles of Mechanics). But I've changed 'scalar component' to 'scalar coefficient' in my answer, as I think that 'coefficient' is a better word here.

Comment: Vector and scalars are geometric objects that exist without coordinate systems. $u_x$ and $u_y$ are numbers that depend on the physical object, ${\vec u}$, and the non-physical coordinate system with which we choose to describe it.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you are right. Velocities are **vectors** that have directions and magnitudes. When you are referring to the magnitude only, use "speed", which is a scalar.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asks about comparing components of vectors which is a legitimate thing to do.